# Could not find driver when connecting AWS RDS in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have a database in AWS RDS but I keep getting error "could not find driver".

This error says that the driver is not enabled. But according to phpinfo() when viewed from my Heroku app, PDO driver for mysql is enabled. My local development via docker can connect and show data from my database in AWS RDS.

I'm expecting this should work fine because PDO mysql driver is showing enabled in Heroku. If AWS RDS does not allow this connection to Heroku, error message should not be about missing driver.

Code to connect to my database:

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("mysql:example.amazonaws.com, "exampleuser", "examplepassword");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error: " . $e->getMessage());
}
```

The DSN and username/password are just example here, I don't want to provide my credentials but this set up works fine on my local development.

Comment: Welcome! Please provide code how you exactly try to connect to the database.

Comment: @teyzer added code.

Comment: Have you tried specifying the hostname in the connection string? Like this: `new PDO('mysql:host=example.amazonaws.com', ...)`

Comment: @teyzer I haven't tried what you suggested but my current set up works on my local development

Comment: Please try to connect to the database like this, and also add the actual error message to the question.